# Is it possible to default a class object to null when using FromQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

```cs
public class Filter
{
    public string Property1 { get;set; }
    public string Property2 { get;set; }
}
```

```
[HttpGet("/search")]
public IActionResult Search([FromQuery] Filter filter)
{
    ...
}
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to default the value of `filter` to null if I were to call `/search`.

Right now `filter` would not be null but each of its properties would be. This is likely because model binding is creating a default instance of the class to fill it with properties it finds in the query string.

I am using `dotnet core 2.2`.

Comment: If you do not pass a parameter to this api method it will be null it is very normal what would you like to do? You will set this object before calling the method!

Comment: It won't be null, I just tried it. It must indeed be the model binding code.

Comment: @marven it is definitely not null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible because model binding will create a default, empty instance of the `Filter` class and attempts to populate its properties from query-string parameters. You can use model validation (e.g. `[Required]` attributes) to make sure the `Filter` object is properly populated. Another, more manual way, might be to create an `IsEmpty()` method and check for every property to have a value in there and use that method to determine whether the `Filter` object actually contains data.

Comment: I'll be accepting your answer, Henk, but I was hoping to be able to find a few references as to where this is happening to back up my assumptions.